# Couchbase N1QL Java "stale = false"

Tags: java, indexing, couchbase, sql++

I'm making a query where I want to set the consistency of it in this way:

```
ParametrizedQuery query = Query.parametrized(queryString, JsonArray.empty(), QueryParams.build().consistency(ScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS));
```

Note how that I want to set `Scanconsistency.REQUEST_PLUS`, but when I make:

```
 int count = bucket.query(query).allRows().size();
```

the execution never ends.

Any idea...?
Thanks in advance

PS: The query i'm using is: `"select * from default where id >=4"`

Comment: why use parameterized instead of simple? also, how many documents are you expecting and what are the versions of couchbase and the sdk?

Comment: I've also tried with Query.simple and the result is the same. Couchbase version is the latest (Couchbase Server 4) and the java-client version (set in the maven dependecy) is 2.2.0.